# Adjusting P-values in ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, p-value

I am working with an experiment on several genes (#41350) based on two factors: `Lcells` (levels: `"pos"`, `"neg"`), `microbe`(levels: `"CR"`, `"GF"`). I have implemented ANOVA test (`aov`) for each individual gene separately comparing `Lcells*microbe`. The result is different p-values of `Lcells`, `microbe` and the interaction for each individual gene (a matrix of 41350*3). Now, how should I adjust p-values? What is the vector I should feed into `p.adjust()`? Shall I adjust all `Lcells` p-values of all genes together, then `microbe` p-values of all genes separately and ...?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest is what is usually done. You typically adjust all the p-values for each factor and their interaction separately.

I do not know what test you are using, but for example, this method is what is used inherently in the functionality of the limma package from the Bioconductor project.

Comment: but that's strange, since before adjusting p-values, for each individual factor I have more than 1500 significants. but after adjusting no significant p-value would remain?!

Comment: Well, this often happens, especially if the conditions you are comparing are biologically only slightly different, or if you have a low number of replicates.

Comment: What method of adjustment are you using?

Comment: I am using 'fdr' method

Comment: ANd I should say that yes I have low number of replicates. only 3 replicates!

Comment: Is your aim to validate the findings, also? If so, the top n genes are still the ones that you would like to use for validation, because FDR does not change the ranking of the genes. In addition, not having any significant p-values left does not (necessarily) mean that you do not have any differences between the conditions, you just have a low power to detect these differences.

Comment: Depending on the test that you are using, you might consider filtering your data set using e.g. standard deviation of low expression before running the tests and adjusting the p-values. That is, if haven't already. This typically leaves you with more DEG genes.