# p-value adjustment/correction on main effects & interactions (F-tests / ANOVA)

Tags: anova, p-value, multiple-comparisons, f-test

I performed 8 ANOVAs on the same subjects with different dependent variables.
We tested the significance of each term & interactions using F-tests (ANOVA). A reviewer asks us if we have applied corrections for multiple comparison.. But it's **not usual practice to adjust p values of the main effects and interactions**... Indeed, **p-values adjustments are usually applied to post-hoc tests performed of omnibus ANOVAs, and not directly on the F-tests..** Could you help me to explain to the reviewer ?...

(I know that same kind of questions ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16276/do-i-need-p-value-adjustment-for-multiple-anovas-on-the-same-dataset) & [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71346/adjusting-p-values-in-anova)..) have been asked before but there is no real answers..)

Comment: If you ran 8 ANOVAs this sounds like a fishing expedition that is in need of serious discounting, e.g., serious multiplicity adjustment.

Comment: What does it mean exactly? I have 3 tests for each ANOVA (two main effects and one interaction), so it means I have 3*8 comparisons that I should correct ?!

Comment: Since you are fitting 8 separate models you should multiplicity adjust for the 8.  Not as sure about the 3.